# Error when reading Layer from .gpkg with readOGR into R and writing it to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, r

---

### About the **SessionInfo()** I work with:

- R version 3.4.2
- rgdal version:  rgdal_1.2-13
- sf version: sf_0.5-4

---

### The problem:

Recently I started to work with Geopackages .gpkg in R. The goal is to read a layer into R, do simple selection and write it to PostgreSQL.

I found two options to load the data from .gpkg into R:

**Example, which works well:**

The data can be downloaded from this [GIS-Browser](https://maps.zh.ch/) -> Select "Naturgefahrenkarten" and choose format .gpkg

```
natrualHazards1 <- readOGR(dsn= "pathto.gpkg", "WB_SYN_GK_F") # readOGR
natrualHazards2 <- st_read(dsn= "pathto.gpkg", layer = "WB_SYN_GK_F") # st_read
```

To write it into PostgreSQL I chose the pgInsert from the rpostgis Library

```
pgInsert(con, name=c("public",paste(c("tablename"),collapse="")), 
     naturalHazards1, 
     geom = "geom", df.mode = FALSE,
     overwrite = TRUE,
     df.geom = c("geom",paste(c("(MultiPolygon,2056)"),collapse="")), geog = FALSE)
```

**Example, which causes error:**

The data can be downloaded from this [GIS-Browser](https://maps.zh.ch/) -> Select "Amtliche Vermessung in Farbe" and choose format .gpkg

```
landuse1 <- readOGR(dsn= fgdb, "Bodenbedeckung_BoFlaeche_Area") # readOGR
```

> Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
>     Multiple incompatible geometries: wkbPolygon: 1549; NA: 1268

```
landuse2 <- st_read(dsn= "pathto.gpkg", layer = "Bodenbedeckung_BoFlaeche_Area) # st_read

conn = dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), dbname = "dbname", user= "postgres", password = "password", host = "localhost", port = 5432) 
st_write_db(conn, landuse2 , drop=TRUE)
```

The error is caused while writing to the PostgreSQL db.

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : FEHLER:  Spalte Â»geometrieÂ« existiert nicht
>   LINE 1: ...bedeckung set wkb_geometry = ST_GeomFromEWKB(cast(Geometrie ...
>                                                                ^
>   HINT:  Vielleicht wurde beabsichtigt, auf die Spalte Â»bodenbedeckung.GeometrieÂ« zu verweisen.
>   )

---

### Hint:

In order to test the object of class sf "landuse" I tried to make a simple conversion to a SpatialDataFrame using this code:

```
landuse_sp <- as(landuse2, "Spatial")
```

> Error in as_Spatial(geom, IDs = row.names(from)) : 
>     conversion from feature type sfc_GEOMETRY to sp is not supported

---

## Questions:

1. What's the problem of readOGR in the second example, how can I learn more about the problem in order to resolve it.
2. What do I have to consider writing objects of class sf to PostgreSQL?
3. Could the errors be caused from a storing problem?
4. Somebody has an idea how to read the second example into R and save it from there to PostgreSQL?

Comment: why use R? just using ogr2ogr would seem easier to me

Comment: Thanks for the hint. In the end I loaded the data as follows in the command line:

cd \"to the folder containing the data" 
ls -file | % { ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=db user=user password=pw" $_.fullname Bodenbedeckung_BoFlaeche_Area -a_srs EPSG:2056 -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -nln public.tablename -append }

Comment: But the described errors are not solved yet